# Selenium Endly Java issue

Tags: java, selenium, endly

When I try to run selenium test with endly, my JDK version is 1.8_161

I see the following error on running:

```
endly –r test
```

Here is the error:

```
[init[test]selenium.run unknown error: connection refused
Build info: version: '3.4.0', revision: 'unknown', ti error]
unknown error: connection refused
Build info: version: '3.4.0', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
System info: host: 'VA0001’ ip: ****', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.12.5', java.version: '1.8.0_161'
```

Here is my test file:
@test.yaml

```
defaults:
  target:
     URL: ssh://127.0.0.1/
     credentials: localhost
pipeline:
  init:
    action: selenium:start
    version: 3.4.0
    port: 8085
    sdk: jdk:1.8
  test:
    action: selenium:run
    browser: firefox
    remoteSelenium:
      URL: http://127.0.0.1:8085
    commands:
      - get(http://127.0.0.1:8080/form.html)
      - (#name).clear
      - (#name).sendKeys('dummy 123')
      - (#typeId).clear()
      - (xpath://SELECT[@id='typeId']/option[text()='type1']).click()
      - (#submit).click
      - command: CurrentURL = CurrentURL()
        exit: $CurrentURL:/dummy/
        sleepTimeMs: 1000
        repeat: 10
      - PageSource = pageSource()  
    expect:
      PageSource: /dummy 123/
```

Comment: try to get the latest version of sdk and firefox

Comment: if this does not work run again with endly  -r=test -d=true, it will create logs  with complete terminal stdin and stdout, then please share it